# Error al configurar Rotativa Net Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, rotativa

estoy configurando una Demo para ocupar y entender el uso de Rotativa, ya que requiero generar reportes en PDF.
Al momento de querer ir a la vista me arroja el error que dejo en la siguiente imagen:
[image: error que se produce]

Y lo que seria la configuración de Rotativa, la tengo en la clase program.cs, a continuación el código

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
var app = builder.Build();

IWebHostEnvironment env = app.Environment;


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

var env1 = env.WebRootPath;
app.Run();
Rotativa.AspNetCore.RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env1, "wwwroot\\Rotativa");
```

muchas gracias por la ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que dejar al final asi:

```
IWebHostEnvironment env = app.Enviroment;
Rotativa.ASpNetCore.RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "../Rotativa");
```

Imagen del código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas necesarias para compartir el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.